# Rendering dynamic HTML(angularjs content) content after ajax call in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular getting stuck after making ajax call. How do I render/compile the html content once you inject in DOM so that I can still use the AngularJs functions.

Due to the way my backend is set up I have to get content via ajax ($http). And I am making the app without jQuery. I tried $compile and $apply but didn't work. What am I missing here.

I have the code set up at http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/RB7FQ/3/ . I want the second div content to have the same properties as the first div.

---

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="section">
  <input ng-model="contentA">
  <div>
      And the input is: {{contentA}}
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="MyAjax" class="section">
  <div id="dumpAjax">
    {{ajaxData}}
  </div>
  <button ng-click=getajax()> Get Ajax</button>
</div>
```

---

### SCRIPT

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {

}

function MyAjax($scope){
  var data = '<input ng-model="contentB">{{contentB}}';

  $scope.getajax = function(){
    $scope.ajaxData = data;
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were you , I would look for a solution that would allow you to not have to inject HTML as a string from your script.  For instance, is there a way you can keep that <input> tag in your HTML and have your $scope drive whether it is visible or not?

Comment: I have to get the HTML codes via ajax due to the codebase I use which has smarty templates that has built in translation functionality

Comment: Why dont you use `ng-include` and point it to the ajax endpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` is not available **1.2 and later verison of angular**...

so you should use `ng-bind-html` which creates a binding that will innerHTML the result of evaluating the expression into the current element in a **secure way**.

using `$scope` variable in your string make it unsafe, so you should use `$sce.trustAsHtml` but this time variables in your string cannot be bind because they will be not compiled...

basically you should **compile** your string in order to bind your variables. Here comes custom directives you can create a directive which can replace with **ng-html-bind**...

Writing a custom directive which extends `ng-bind-html` with some extra functions can be a solution...

here is my [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/NBZXJ9BP76kPwpSddFMa?p=preview)

and here is your updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RB7FQ/4/) with my solution...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `{{ajaxData}}`, you should use something like:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="ajaxData"></div>
```

However, you'd still need to set the proper model to bind the `contentB` and get it working.

Comment: Thanks Shomz... the ng-bind-html-unsafe works. But the binding is still not working. Do you have link to a reference were I can get the proper model?

Comment: You're welcome. Seems like the ng-model can't handle it just by compiling and that you'd have to create a custom directive to do that kind of a "double parsing".