# dynamic html in angular js

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

I have tried to display HTML from database and in this HTML there are some Variables or scope for display, but that time it is considering it as a hard coded HTML. Please suggest me the solution for the same.

Response html

ptag {{ownerName}} ptag

browser output

{{ownerName}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular you have to tell the application that the HTML can be trusted.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

In the HTML you should set a html variable like:

```
<div ng-bind-html="htmlFromDB"></div>
```

in the controller you would use $sce

```
$scope.htmlFromDB = $sce.trustAsHtml(//somehtml)
```

This can be super dangerous, and add vulnerabilities to Cross site scripting. So make sure you know where that HTML came from!

Comment: its working for html but our question is we added html dynamically and that dynamic html contain ng-model ,ng-repeat, scope angular tag that not bind with our actual data because its run time added.

Comment: you may want to check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536477/rendering-dynamic-htmlangularjs-content-content-after-ajax-call-in-angularjs.  Using the answer there I was able to create a working example of dynamic html with angular binding: http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/RGNdkJ

Comment: i got solution refer link as below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database