# Render html tag from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have some values as amount like `1000, 2000, <b>3000</b>, <4000>, <b>5000</b>` inside JSON as an API response. I want to render this response inside a table. So I tried ng-bind-html. BUT it is showing only the value which are having  tags like 3000,5000. I want to show all values , 1000,2000,4000 as a plain string and 3000,5000 in BOLD/or any other HTML tag.

```
angular.forEach($scope.arr2.test,function(item)
  $scope.res=$sce.trustAsHtml(item.amount);
  return $scope.res;
});
```

On HTML side, I have something like this

```
<td id="price" class="edit" ng-repeat="pro in d.procedure" ng-bind-html="valueCheck(d._id,pro._id,hos._id)"></td>
```

Comment: se http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536477/rendering-dynamic-htmlangularjs-content-content-after-ajax-call-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` for this. But please be mindful of the security concerns here.

You can find more details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)

Do make sure you sanitize your strings, to prevent security vulnerabilities

Comment: After injecting Sanitize, ng-bind-html is giving me same result as $sce.trustAsHtml(item.amount); means it is only showing the value which has HTML tag AND ng-bind-html-unsafe is not giving me any value

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to download the ng-sanitize js
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

and then inject ng-sanitize to angular module.
then you can use ng-bind-html and ng-bind-html-unsafe

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-sanitize module for the same - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/8z6t7ooh/)

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
```